# How can I reconstruct an image after it has been downprojected with PCA in R?

Tags: r, pca

How can I reconstruct an image after it has been down-projected with PCA in R?

If the original image was N dimensional, I down-projected it to 10 dimensions.
How can I reconstruct an N dimensional image now, from the 10 dimensional?
Of course I am aware there will be loss of information.

Comment: The following video might be helpful https://class.coursera.org/ml-003/lecture/87

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly then you want to reconstruct an image represented as a matrix X using first 10 principal components. Assuming that you have the original image, you can do this by first decomposing the matrix using the function "svd" and then keeping first 10 singular values.

```
   s <- svd(X)    #perform singular value decomposition
   s$d[11:N] <- 0 #keep first 10 components
   Xre <- s$u %*% diag(s$d) %*% t(s$v) #reconstruct
```

I am editing to include PCA version.

```
   p <- prcomp(X)
   Xre <- p$x[,1:10] %*% t(p$rotation[,1:10]) #multiply rotated matrix and rotation matrix
```

Comment: @user3111311 PCA and svd are very strongly related. Indeed svd is the preferred way of implementing PCA.

Comment: Since the default for `prcomp` is `center = TRUE` I believe you need to also add `p$center` to reconstruct the original data.